# Any expand URL?

Tags: java, android, url

Anyone know any function which will expand short URL to get coordinates in Android? Like: I have a short URL for which I am getting the expanded URL as follows in browser:

[This is link](https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/Statue+of+Liberty+National+Monument/@40.6892494,-74.0466891,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x89c25090129c363d:0x40c6a5770d25022b!8m2!3d40.6892494!4d-74.0445004)

I want to extract the coordinates from this in Android.

Answer (score 1):

You Can try this

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String expandedURL1=expand("YOUR SHORT URL");
                Log.d("Expanded", "run: "+expandedURL1);
            }
        }).start();

    }

    public static String expand(String url) {
        String s3 = "";
        try {
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
            int s = connection.getInputStream().read();
            URL s2 = connection.getURL();
            s3 = String.valueOf(s2);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return s3;
    }


}
```

You will get the expanded url in logcat
D/Expanded: run:"Expanded URL"